# jquery tabs add space at the top

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Ok,
Here is the deal. I installed jQuery tabs from http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#mouseover

But, it looks to be working fine only with first two tabs, when I activate tab 3, 4, .... it adds some blank space before each div and so every div moves down for about 10px.

My script is not a big deal:

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        event: "mouseover"
        });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
  <div id="tabs">

    <ul class="tabs">
      <li><a href="#tab-1">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab-2">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab-3">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab-4">4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab-5">5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab-6">6</a></li>    
    </ul>

    <div id="1"></div>
    <div id="2"></div>    
    <div id="3"></div>
    <div id="4"></div>
    <div id="5"></div>
    <div id="6"></div>

  </div>
```

Comment: I've created a jsfiddle with the code that you have provided and I can't reproduce the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/F4Hg6/ , so my guess is that you are having problems with your css. Why don't you create a jsfiddle reproducing your problem so we can help you.

Comment: here is my version and the problem is still there http://jsfiddle.net/B4tq2/ Check it out, there are no CSS attached

Comment: Sorry, I can't see what the problem is.

Comment: did you try to hover over tabs? it keep moving them to the bottom of the page

Comment: Ok, now I can see it, thanks!

Comment: Although your `id's` are correct in your jsFiddles, the `id's` in your Question starts with a number which should never be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is to close each div, there is a superfluous **br**

```
</div> <br /> 
         ^
         ^
         ^ 
       (remove this br) 

       <div id="tab-n".....>
          // something
       </div>
```